# Fix "improper use of releaseJob() without a matching number of createTmpFiles() calls for jobId" Flink

Tags: scala, apache-flink

When I run my flink application in the Logs I am seeing this warning:

```
improper use of releaseJob() without a matching number of createTmpFiles() calls for jobId
```

I've search in flink's source code and found that line in [FileCache.java](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/8674b69964eae50cad024f2c5caf92a71bf21a09/flink-runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/filecache/FileCache.java#L229). But can not see where in my code I am causing this warning to raise. Any ideas where I should look at?

Comment: Are you still having this problem? I am facing this issue and it is not a Nothing-to-worry issue since my job cannot be released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an issue with your code but a Flink-internal bug. Can you provide us your application (or a minimal version) that reproduces the problem?

Nothing to worry about, the log message is simple unnecessary. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-10283

Comment: Sure, this is the code: https://github.com/elbaulp/DPASF. You may run any of the tests and should see the Warning. 

For example: `testOnly com.elbauldelprogramador.discretizers.PIDiscretizerTransformerSpec`

Comment: Nothing to worry about, the log message is simple unnecessary. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-10283

Comment: Thanks, could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I've modified my original answer.

Comment: I am facing the same issue and it is not a Nothing-to-worry issue since my job cannot be released. @ChesnaySchepler